# Is there any function to locate all occurrences in a column of PySpark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following PySpark dataframe

| A |
| --- |
| 1001 |
| 1110 |
| 1000 |

I want to find all occurrences of `1` in this column and put it into a new column in some way like this:

| A | Occurrences |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 0,3 |
| 1110 | 0,1,2 |
| 1000 | 0 |

I tried the `locate` function as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
dfa_occ = dfa.withColumn('Occurrences', F.locate('1', (F.col('A'))-1) )
```

However this only extracts the first occurrence of `1`, while I need to find all of them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [`posexplode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode.html#pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode) and the aggregate result back into a list. `split` in this example splits the string into letters.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1001',), ('1110',), ('1000',)], ['A'])

df = (df
    .select('*', F.posexplode(F.split('A', '(?!$)')))
    .filter('col = 1')
    .groupBy('A')
    .agg(F.collect_list('pos').alias('Occurrences'))
)
df.show()
# +----+-----------+
# |   A|Occurrences|
# +----+-----------+
# |1001|     [0, 3]|
# |1000|        [0]|
# |1110|  [0, 1, 2]|
# +----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way using array's higher-order functions `transform` and `filter`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = df.withColumn(
    "Occurrences",
    F.filter(
        F.transform(F.split("A", ""), lambda x, i: F.when(x == 1, i)), 
        lambda x: x.isNotNull()
    )
)

result.show()
# +----+-----------+
# |   A|Occurrences|
# +----+-----------+
# |1001|     [0, 3]|
# |1110|  [0, 1, 2]|
# |1000|        [0]|
# +----+-----------+
```